# Smallest closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ and $\sup S = b$ and $\inf S= a$ and $a$ and $b$ are not equal. prove that $[a,b]$ is the smallest closed interval containing the set $S$.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean $sup$ $S$ $= b$?

Comment: Prove that $S \subset [a,b]$ and $S \not\subset [\alpha,\beta]$ for $\alpha > a$ or $\beta < b$.

Comment: please can you give a more hint!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, clearly $[a,b]$ does contain S. Now, let's see if $I:=[a+e,b-e]$ can contains S, for some value $e$; choose
$ 0<e<(b-a)/2$;  if the interval I did contain S, we would have:

$infS=a<a+e <b-e<b=SupS$

And we conclude: No SUP for you !

Comment: can you explain the last part of your solution?

Comment: you mean the string of inequalities? Well, if the interval I:=[a+e,b-e] contained S, then it would contain SupS=a and InfS=b. But it cannot, since , by def. for any e>0, a+e>InfS and b-e< SupS, so neither the Sup nor the Inf will be contained in such I.

Comment: can you help me in explaining that [a,b] contains S

Comment: Well, by definition, [a,b]:={$x:a\leq x \leq b $}